# How do I grab the section title and change the title of the slides in the section?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm writing a script in VBA to change the Title's of the slide to the section title. I have multiple sections and I want to iterate though the ppt to change all the titles of the slides to have the same section title as its section.

I've tried finding how to grab the section title and set it to the slide's title.

```
Sub test()

ActivePresentation.Slides.Name = ActivePresentation.SectionProperties(sectionName)


End Sub
```

I need to add iteration, I need i believe syntax is messed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully something like the following is what you're looking for. The code

1. Loops through each slide in the `ActivePresentation`, adding a title if there isn't already one.
2. Changes the title text by getting the [`sectionIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slide.sectionindex) property of the slide, and then using that index in the [`SectionProperties.Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.sectionproperties.name) method to retrieve the corresponding text.

---

```
Sub ChangeMyTitles()
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim titleShape As Shape

    If ActivePresentation.SectionProperties.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        With sld
            If Not .Shapes.HasTitle Then
                Set titleShape = .Shapes.AddTitle
            Else
                Set titleShape = .Shapes.Title
            End If

            titleShape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = ActivePresentation.SectionProperties.Name(.sectionIndex)
        End With
    Next sld
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to modify a different placeholder than the title, you could do something like this. Based on your screenshot, I assume that the placeholder you want to modify is the 3rd one (title is 1st, body is 2nd, and chapter is 3rd), but you might have to change the `3` below.

```
Sub ChangeMyChapters()
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim chapterShape As Shape

    If ActivePresentation.SectionProperties.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        With sld
            Set chapterShape = .Shapes.Placeholders(3)
            chapterShape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = ActivePresentation.SectionProperties.Name(.sectionIndex)
        End With
    Next sld
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome, do you happen to know the "Chapter" property, i believe its a textholder, its just above the Title/

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're talking about. Can you maybe add a screenshot of a sample slide, pointing it out? Or maybe a screenshot of slide in slidemaster view so I can see which element it is?

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/QDe9sPU) I circled it, hopefully this will help.

Comment: Yes that helps. It might be some time but I'll try to take a look later today.

Comment: Thanks, your code worked earlier for the title. Just had a change of plans with the PPT. I've been trying to modify the code. VBA is kinda confusing, LOL.

Comment: See my edit. This worked for me in testing. You might need to tweak slightly.

Comment: Perfect! yes this is what I wanted. Thanks !